# Flutter using videoplayer in a listview returning multiple errors

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a tabBarView with a listview in one of the tabs.I have the gesture detector below inside the listview. I am trying to show some newtwork videos.

```
VideoPlayerController playercontroller;
VideoPlayerController  retcontroller(String varainatVideo){
    if(playercontroller == null){
      playercontroller = VideoPlayerController.network(varainatVideo);
    }
    return playercontroller;
  }

GestureDetector(
child:AspectRatio(
aspectRatio: 16/9,
child:Stack(
children:<Widgets>[

Chewie(

 retcontroller(stringVideo),

   cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(),
    showControls:false,
   ),

     ]
   )
  )
);
```

whenever I switch from that tab bar to another and try to navigate to another page in the second tabBar I get a black screen instead of the normal page.but when I remove the videoPage I dont get this problem and get this in the console

```
I/flutter (19985): Another exception was thrown: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
I/flutter (19985): Another exception was thrown: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

logs from the Debug console:
I have tried to figure out what, but I cant seem to get the `Hero Tag` associated with the `videoPlayerController` in order to set it to null.

```
I/flutter (19985): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (19985): The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
I/flutter (19985): There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
I/flutter (19985): Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (typically a PageRoute subtree), each Hero
I/flutter (19985): must have a unique non-null tag.
I/flutter (19985): In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag:
I/flutter (19985): VideoPlayerController#3144c(VideoPlayerValue(duration: null, size: null, position: 0:00:00.000000,
I/flutter (19985): buffered: [], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription:
I/flutter (19985): null))
I/flutter (19985): Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes:
I/flutter (19985): # Hero(tag: VideoPlayerController#3144c(VideoPlayerValue(duration: null, size: null, position: 0:00:00.000000, buffered: [], isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: falsevolume: 1.0, errorDescription: null)), state: _HeroState#b5c8f)
I/flutter (19985): # └KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#44acd]
I/flutter (19985): #  └AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1.7, renderObject: RenderAspectRatio#78caa relayoutBoundary=up2)
I/flutter (19985): #   └VideoPlayer(state: _VideoPlayerState#62908)
I/flutter (19985): #    └Container
I/flutter (19985): #     └LimitedBox(maxWidth: 0.0, maxHeight: 0.0, renderObject: RenderLimitedBox#9e9b5)
I/flutter (19985): #      └ConstrainedBox(BoxConstraints(biggest), renderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#1b4cb)
I/flutter (19985):
I/flutter (19985): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (19985): #0      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:191:13)
I/flutter (19985): #1      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:201:10)
I/flutter (19985): #2      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4784:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not use singleton `VideoPlayerController` for multiple `Chewie` instance, Chewie use controller(the first arguments) as hero's tag

Answer (score 1):

```
class Videos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoPlayerPageState createState() => _VideosState();
}

class _VideosState extends State<Videos> {
  List<String> videoList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    final videoList = _dir
        .listSync()
        .map((item) => item.path)
        .where((item) =>
            item.endsWith(".mp4") ||
            item.endsWith(".avi") ||
            item.endsWith(".webm"))
        .toList(growable: false);
    if (videoList != null) {
      if (videoList.length > 0) {
        return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 16),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int index) {
              if (index >= videoList.length) {
                return null;
              }
              return VideoPlayerScreen(
                path: videoList[index],
              );
            });
      }
    }
    return VideoPlayerScreen(
      path: videoList[0],
    );
  }
}
```